# Java package issue

Tags: java, package

I am trying to import a package found at `/home/jirwin/ptplot5.8/ptolemy/plot/plot.jar`. I am using `import ptolemy.plot.*` and compiling with `javac -cp /home/jirwin/ptplot5.8/ptolemy/plot/plot.jar The Class.java`. When I run (using java -cp ...same... TheClass) I get `Error:Could not find or create main class TheClass`.

When I take away the `-cp` from the `java` call the `Could not find or create` error goes away...

I know this must be something simple but I can't figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify that the classpath is a single jar files -- as you seem to be doing --  then Java won't find any classes outside of that jar file. You need your classpath to include *both* the jar file and the location of your compiled classes. You can use "." to mean the current directory; i.e.,

```
java -cp .:/home/jirwin/ptplot5.8/ptolemy/plot/plot.jar TheClass
```

Note the "dot colon" prepended to the beginning of the classpath.

Comment: I think that did it! I didn't know that -cp in a sense overwrote the CLASSPATH variable. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your full package name in front of your .class when you run it with java.  Otherwise it looks in the wrong place, or something.  (I don't understand java well enough to give you the "why" but it's the idea.)

`java -cp /home/jirwin/ptplot5.8/ptolemy/plot/plot.jar {package}.TheClass`

Comment: Hmmm, my code isn't explicitly added to a package which means it's in the Default package. I am trying to use plot.jar as an external library. I'm not extending it or writing part of it.